# Create Postgres FDW using the postgres super user yet have read only access to the remote schema

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I am trying to create an FDW using the `postgres` super user credentials using the following steps -

1. My super user is `postgres`
2. CREATE SERVER `testfdw`
   FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER `postgres_fdw`
   OPTIONS (host '10.10.10.171', dbname 'testdb', port '5432', fetch_size '50000');
3. I have created a read only remote user called `testdb_read_only_user` on `testdb` and granted read only privileges to all tables and sequences and functions in there
4. I now create a user mapping for my local db super user `postgres`
5. CREATE USER MAPPING
   FOR `postgres`
   SERVER `testfdw`
   OPTIONS (user 'testdb_read_only_user', password 'testpasswrd')
6. Then I run IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER `testfdw` INTO `test_local_schema`;
7. Now when I try to create a new foreign table into `test_local_schema` using the `postrges` super user, I am still able to create one, but the actual behaviour I expect is a permission denied error and my user mapping is based on the read only user I created on the Remote DB

Am I missing something here. Please guide.

Comment: I don't understand your expectation.  Creating a foreign table does not write to the foreign server, it writes the description of the foreign table to the local server.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign schema test_local_schema is owned by postgres(Superuser) and PostgreSQL treating it as a local schema(on target) gives you option to create a new table, Now when you are creating a new foreign table in test_local_schema postgres will check below constraints

1. The name of the foreign table must be distinct from the name of any other foreign table, table, sequence, index, view, or materialized view in the same schema.
2. To create a foreign table, you must have USAGE(read) privilege on
   the    foreign server, as well as USAGE privilege on all column
   types used    in the table
3. CREATE privilege on the target schema.

As your user mapping has read-only user in source database you should be able to fetch data in order to create a foreign table in target database, however whenever you will update and insert new data it will give you error as testdb_read_only_user is not having any update/insert privileges.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createforeigntable.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-importforeignschema.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch Nikhil! You are right I am not able to update or delete any tables on the foreign schema using the read only user. The other thing I noticed is that though I am able to create a foreign table in my local schema using the postgres super user, the same new table is not reflected in the foreign schema when I actually try logging into the foreign database to see.

Comment: Glad to help :)